# PHP issue with cookies on server

Tags: php

I am checking if the cookie exists or not. Code run perfect on localhost but not working on server.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['checkuser']))
{
  // Create a cookie
}
else
{
  // do other other action
}
```

page is not being load on if accessing from webserver. but on localhost its work fine. is there is some setting that I need to do for this ?

Comment: the page is not loading or the `COOKIE` is not setting?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? "Not working" is not a correct explanation of the problem.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which server you're running this on - `COOKIE`s are stored on the client side. Then again, have you enabled cookies from non-local hosts?

Comment: How are you setting the cookies?

Comment: @Jocelyn: Its not even giving any error. and not loading page either.

Comment: @david: setcookie("chkuser", "mysite", $expire);

Comment: What I am trying to do is

check cookie exist or not. If its not Insert user Ip,agent and os info in DB and set cookie for ten minutes.

If cookie exists I am simply extending its expire time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error is "the page is not loading" then it is almost certainly not related to the code you posted.  You mention in a comment that you're doing some database calls in code you didn't post - that's far more likely to cause trouble than an `isset()` call.

What error are you seeing?  If you are seeing just a blank page, that's likely a syntax error which is being logged to the server's error log rather than to the screen, for security purposes.  Check your server's error logs for an associated message.

It's likely your server is running either a different version of PHP or a different security level (PHP safe mode, for instance) which is causing it to fail on the server but not on your machine.  Alternatively, it may be failing to connect to the server's database.

Please update your question with more information (more code and/or the exact error message would be a good start) if this isn't enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: I am getting this message on Chrome

"Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://website.com/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

when I click on reload page appears.

Comment: a [500 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) indicates that the server failed to handle the request for some reason.  The specific reason will (usually) be logged to your server's error logs.  Without a larger code example / the exact error message, it's not possible for me to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Since you say you see the page load successfully upon a refresh, this doesn't sound like your problem, but here's some potential causes of 500 errors in PHP: http://wiki.lunarpages.com/500_Error_and_PHP